# Show all filter on Aurelia value converter

Tags: javascript, aurelia

At the moment my app currently displays exercises and then filters them by muscle group using a select option. I'm struggling to understand how to initially display all of them.

As soon as the app is loaded it is already filtered by a muscle group, or if it is filtered by a value of 'all' it doesn't display anything as this is not a specified muscle group in my JSON. It is organised in the following way:

Select option to call filter (muscle filters is just an array off all the muscle groups)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="muscle">Show:</label>
      <select id="muscle" ref="muscle">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option repeat.for="muscle of muscleFilters" value.bind="muscle">${muscle}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Display

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" repeat.for="exercise of exercises | sortMuscle:muscle.value">
${exercise.title}
</div>
```

Sorting Function

```
export class SortMuscleValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName) {
    return array
      .slice(0).filter(function (i) {
          return (i.muscle === propertyName);
      });
  }
}
```

How can I display all the data when the 'all' option is selected? I also have a search function which needs to clear all the filters when submitted so it can search all the data.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a simple `if` statement in your value converter:

```js
// Note: convertor name is misleading - it does filtering, not sorting
export class SortMuscleValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName) {
    if (propertyName === 'all') {
      return array;
    }

    // Simplified filter
    return array.filter(i => i.muscle === propertyName);
  }
}
```

---

As an alternative, here's a generic `FilterValueConverter` that you can use to filter on any property (using equality):

```js
export class FilterValueConverter {
  toView(array, propertyName, filter) {
    if (!filter) {
      return array;
    }

    return array.filter(item => item[propertyName] === filter);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<!-- option for All needs to have an empty value -->
<option value="">All</option>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" 
     repeat.for="exercise of exercises | filter:'muscle':muscle.value">
  ${exercise.title}
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on answer. Appreciate it. I did try to use an if statement inside the converter before, but it didnt return the original array!